# How can I validate an Azure AD JWT Token in Java?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD JWT token that is obtained using Msal library but when I try to validate this token something is wrong:

***Client: A Sharepoint Web Part***

```
 const config = {
     auth: {
         clientId: "xxxxx",
         authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yyyyyy"
     }
 };

 const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(config);

 let accessTokenRequest = {
     scopes: ["user.read"],
     loginHint: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName,
     extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}
 }

 myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(
  function(accessTokenResponse) { 
  // Acquire token silent success 
  let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
```

I'm trying to retrieve the publick key from:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/.well-known/openid-configuration but with this public key I can never redirect to: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

Is there any other way to obtain the public key in this case?

***Server: Validation***

```
public PublicKey getPublicKeyFromParams(String e, String n){

    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(n);

    BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);

    byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(e);

    BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

    KeyFactory keyFactory;

    RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusInt, exponentInt);

        try {

            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            return keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    return null;

}

@Test

public void name() throws Exception {

    String jwt = "xxxxxxx";

    KeyPair keyPair = Keys.keyPairFor(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256);

    String e = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString((((RSAPublicKeyImpl) keyPair.getPublic()).getPublicExponent()).toByteArray());

    String n = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString((((RSAPublicKeyImpl) keyPair.getPublic()).getModulus()).toByteArray());

    System.out.println("Public Key: " + Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));

    System.out.println("Public Key Exponent: " + e);

    System.out.println("Public Key Modulus: " + n);

    String jws = Jwts.builder().setSubject("pepe").signWith(keyPair.getPrivate()).compact();

    System.out.println("Generated JWS:" + jws);

    PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromParams(e, n);

    Jwt parsedJWs = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(publicKey).build().parse(jws);

    System.out.println("Parsed JWS: " + parsedJWs);

    publicKey = getPublicKeyFromParams(eValue, nValue);

    System.out.println("Azure PublicKey fron n-e: " + publicKey);

    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    Certificate cert = factory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(

    DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("cccccccccccccccccc")));

    publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

    System.out.println("Azure PublicKey from x5c: " + publicKey);

    Jwt jwtParsed = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(publicKey).build().parse(jwt);

    System.out.println(jwtParsed);

}

public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String key){

    try{

        byte[] byteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);

        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: Hi @JimXu. Thanks for your reply. I have added my code.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to validate Azure AD access token, we can try to use the sdk `java-jwt` and `jwks-rsa` to implememnt it.

For example

1. Install SDK via maven

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
      <version>8.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
      <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Code

   a. validate the signature

   ```
    String token="<your AD token>";
     DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
     System.out.println(jwt.getKeyId());

     JwkProvider provider = null;
     Jwk jwk =null;
     Algorithm algorithm=null;

     try {
         provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys"));
         jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
         algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
         algorithm.verify(jwt);// if the token signature is invalid, the method will throw SignatureVerificationException
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (JwkException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }catch(SignatureVerificationException e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

     }
   ```

Comment: Hi JIm!. Thanks for your response.

With your code I have the same problem:

I have obtained the token with:

 myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
          // Acquire token silent success
          // call API with token
          let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;

Comment: The validation error with your example is this:

The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA

Have you got any idea?

Comment: @vcima Is that you use sdk `msal.js` to require token?

Comment: Hi @Jim XU, yes I'm using the Msal library inside a Sharepoint WebPart with this import: import {UserAgentApplication} from "msal";. Is there a problem with this?.

Comment: const config = {
     auth: {
         clientId: "xxxxx",
         authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yyyyyy"
     }
 };

 const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(config);

 let accessTokenRequest = {
     scopes: ["user.read"],
     loginHint: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName,
     extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}
 }

 myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(
  function(accessTokenResponse) { 
  // Acquire token silent success 
  let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;

Comment: @vcima If you use SDK to require access token for Microsoft graph resource. We will meet the error. Because,  we need to validate the access token in the server.  And we cannot validate the access token in chide application. So we will get the error.

Comment: @vcima According to my test, if we validate the access token with our own resource, it is ok.

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu, we are validating the token in the server

Comment: @vcima if  the access token is required for Microsoft graph, we need to validate it in Microsoft graph server. But we have no way to access it. In fact, we hen we use the access token to call Microsoft graph,  the graph server will help us validate access token.

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu,  We don't need to use Microsoft Graph. WIth the token, that we have obtained with Msal we want to call our own API, and we need to check if this token is valid when we work with our API

Comment: @vicma Can you validate the token in https://jwt.io successfully?

Answer (score 5):

With this change, the validation works fine.

```
let accessTokenRequest = {
    scopes:["clientId/.default"],
    loginHint: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName,
    extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks vcima, you just saved me after countless hours. It seems that the access_token generated from msal is actually *invalid* when generated with `scopes:['user.read']`, and valid with `['your client id/.default']`, verifiable via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). Also see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/521#issuecomment-577400515)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the new keys from microsoft for the above code to work. Change:

provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys"));

to

provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys"));

For the example above there are some dependencies missing, the correct sample should be:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/jwks-rsa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
        <version>0.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And code:

```
String token="YOUR JWT";
        DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
        System.out.println(jwt.getKeyId());

        JwkProvider provider = null;
        Jwk jwk =null;
        Algorithm algorithm=null;

        try {
            provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys"));
            jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
            algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
            algorithm.verify(jwt);// if the token signature is invalid, the method will throw SignatureVerificationException
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JwkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SignatureVerificationException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
```

Comment: When i tried this code, I am getting sslhand shake exception at the below line.                 jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());   Do we need to add any public certificate in the JKS?

Comment: This verifying even expired tokens. Is there any way to customize verification options to include expiry time, issuer etc?